# Error when creating Netsuite script: module does not exist

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I've created a js file, filled with the logic for CS script and uploaded it to the file cabinet.
Afterwards I want to create a script record and select the file, but get the following error when trying to save the script object:

Error
Fail to evaluate script: {"type":"error.SuiteScriptModuleLoaderError","name":"{stack=[Ljava.lang.Object;@62fae4dc, toJSON=org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction@2d7dfa04, name=MODULE_DOES_NOT_EXIST, toString=org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction@1a1478db, id=, message=Module does not exist: N/render.js, TYPE=error.SuiteScriptModuleLoaderError}","message":"","stack":[]}

My CS file:

```
define(['N/render', 'N/currentRecord'],
/**
* @param {render} render
* @param {currentRecord} currentRecord
*/
function(render, currentRecord) {

    function download_file(scriptContext)
    {
        var renderer = render.create();
        //other logic
    }

    return {
        download_file : download_file,
    };
});
```

Did anyone experience this before and know what causes this?

Comment: How are you referring to your module in your client script define, and where is your module file in the filing cabinet relative to the client script file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, it seems all function members of the module are only accessible in server scripts:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4412042824.html

I assume the problem is that the module is not available for CS scripts.
Could anyone validate this assumption?

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you saved the script file with .js extension